# Why is my library not able to expand on the CocoaPods website?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to access my library's information through the CocoaPods website, but I'm not able to. All the other libraries seem to be able to expand (mine is MKWeatherUndergroundKit)

[image]

Here is my podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name         = "MKWeatherUndergroundKit"
s.version      = "0.6"
s.summary      = "A simple iOS and OS X library for retrieving weather information using the Weather Underground API"
s.homepage     = "https://github.com/MendyK/MKWeatherUndergroundKit"
s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
s.author             = { "MendyK" => "myEmail@gmail.com" }
s.social_media_url   = "https://twitter.com/MenndK"
s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/MendyK/MKWeatherUndergroundKit.git", :tag => "0.6"}

s.source_files  = "MKWeatherUndergroundKit/*.{h,m}"
s.resources = "MKWeatherUndergroundKit/Climacons.ttf"
s.requires_arc = true
s.frameworks = 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation'
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should now be good, http://cocoapods.org/pods/MKWeatherUndergroundKit

The problem was that our CocoaDocs server was down, I've manually redeployed your version and am taking a look at the minute.

I've also wrote up an article on my blog post with a lot of useful tips: http://orta.io/rebase/why-cant-i-expand/

Comment: Would you please have a look at my issue that is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128927/why-is-my-libraries-not-able-to-expand-on-the-cocoapods-and-shows-as-objective-c

Comment: The blog post leads to a 404. Can you post the tips here?

Comment: I moved it to the issue template for CocoaDocs: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md - though I dunno why my site is 404ing

Comment: Could you check my pod `FTLinearActivityIndicator` that shows the same problem? I checked the tips in the GH issue. The CocoaDocs page 404s but the link to see errors doesn't work because the server `api.cocoadocs.org` can't be found.