# Why is my libraries not able to expand on the CocoaPods and shows as Objective-c not Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to access my libraries through the CocoaPods website, but I cannot see expand button.
My libraries are:

- NextResponderTextField
- PagedHorizontalView

Here is how they look on cocopods.org website.

**NextResponderTextField**
[image: NextResponderTextField]

**PagedHorizontalView**
[image: PagedHorizontalView]

Besides, when I filter the search for swift I don't see my libraries, I only see them under objective-c although both libraries are swift libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many pods are coming in at once it can take anywhere from 5m to 1hr to get all the data setup for CocoaPods.org's expanded view. When I checked today it was up and running for NextResponderTextField.

That said, there was [a bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/issues/362) that may have stopped the parsing for a few days, but I've gone over all Pods since then.

Comment: Yeah, I can see both pods are fixed. Thanks a lot. Probably, it was that bug because I waited for more than a day.

Answer (score 0):

@orga, I have the same problem with SwiftCheckboxDialog, it was depolyed 4 days ago, and checking this link (http://api.cocoadocs.org:4567/error/SwiftCheckboxDialog/0.1.0) (from one of your debug examples) shows there is no errors

```
{"message":"Could not find any errors, perhaps CocoaDocs has not ran the processing?", "trace" :[]}
```