# "Expand" button not showing for library on CocoaPods website

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I deployed my first pod `AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout` a couple of weeks ago to [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout). It all works fine and it shows up in search on cocoapods.org.

[image: CocoaPods Search screenshot]

However, it doesn't have an <kbd>Expand</kbd> button next to it like most of the other pods, but the three buttons <kbd>Site</kbd>, <kbd>Docs</kbd> and <kbd>Spec</kbd> instead where the <kbd>Spec</kbd> button targets a URL that doesn't exist:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/1.1.0/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout.podspec.json

The correct URL for the podspec is:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/3/7/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/1.1.0/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout.podspec.json

I also found some other questions on Stackoverflow concerning the same issue (unfortunately unanswered):

- [pod trunk push successfully but the CocoaPods link redirect to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998449/pod-trunk-push-successfully-but-the-cocoapods-link-redirect-to-github)
- [KVCardSelectionVC Cocoapod not expanding on cocoapods.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010109/kvcardselectionvc-cocoapod-not-expanding-on-cocoapods-org)
- [Unable to find a specification for my Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833886/unable-to-find-a-specification-for-my-cocoapods)

and one answer to an older similar question mentioning that the CocoaPods server was down at the time:

- [Why is my library not able to expand on the CocoaPods website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240598/why-is-my-library-not-able-to-expand-on-the-cocoapods-website)

Has that been the case when I deployed my pod as well?

#### How can I fix this and get the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button to show on CocoaPods.org?

Answer (score 0):

try redeploy your pods using this link below
http://api.cocoadocs.org:4567/redeploy/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/latest

Also, you can check errors
http://api.cocoadocs.org:4567/error/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout/1.0.0